# Parsing Nagios configuration file

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I need to delete from a Nagios configuration file some services. Here an extract:

```
define service{
    use                     generic-service
    hostgroup_name          d_drivespace
    service_description     D:\ Drive Space
    check_command           check_nt!USEDDISKSPACE!-l D -w 92 -c 97 
}

define service{
    use                     generic-service
    hostgroup_name          e_drivespace
    service_description     E:\ Drive Space
    check_command           check_nt!USEDDISKSPACE!-l E -w 92 -c 97 
}
```

I' ve already tried with AWK:

```
gawk -v RS= -v 'ORS=\n\n' '!/\<D:\\ Drive Space\>/'
```

The problem is that also E:\ Drive Space is deleted.

Any help would be so appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What do you want to delete?

Comment: It works fine on GNU Awk 4.0.2. It deletes the service associated with `D:\ Drive Space`

Comment: Can you try the following command: `$ gawk -v 'RS=' -v 'ORS=\n\n' '!/D:\\ Drive Space/' nagios.cfg` 

This should give the output
`define service{
    use                     generic-service
    hostgroup_name          e_drivespace
    service_description     E:\ Drive Space
    check_command           check_nt!USEDDISKSPACE!-l E -w 92 -c 97 
}`

with `awk --version
GNU Awk 4.1.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement is not clear, I believe you want to print only specific 
 group of lines, if yes then could you please try following. Since I don't have `gawk` in my system so couldn't test OP's command.

```
awk '
NF{
  val=val?val ORS $0:$0
}
/D:\\ Drive Space/{
  flag=1
}
/}/{
  if(!flag){
    print val
  }
  val=flag=""
}
END{
  if(val && !flag){
    print val
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
define service{
    use                     generic-service
    hostgroup_name          e_drivespace
    service_description     E:\ Drive Space
    check_command           check_nt!USEDDISKSPACE!-l E -w 92 -c 97
}
```

Comment: @Daniel, also try to check if your Input_file(s) have CONTROL M characters or not by doing `cat -v Input_file` and if they are there then remove them by doing `tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` and let me know how it goes.